# Rails 3.1 layout specified in controller not overriding layout from parent controller when using Capybara/Selenium

Tags: layout, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber

I have a base controller

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  layout 'admin'
end
```

inherited by another controller

```
class Admin::AdminsController < Admin::BaseController
  layout 'admin_bootstrap'

  ...actions

end
```

Where the child controller overrides the layout specified in the parent controller.

When viewed while running the server, everything works as expected.

But when I run my cucumber tests, the pages are displayed using the 'admin' layout, not the 'admin_bootstrap' layout.

I am in the process of moving this portion of the site over to use the twitter bootstrap framework and am doing it function by function (controller by controller) but this has dampened by spirits a trifle, as expected javascript functions are not working (because the bootstrap assets are not included in the admin layout, but are in the admin_bootstrap layout).

I am sure I am just missing something silly.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Best, 
Tom